# How do I display a .thb file on a web page?

Tags: html, image

To display a preview of a .thb file, I tried using an <img> tag.  However the file does not display.

```
<img src="/mydir/myfile.thb" />
```

How do embed such a file on my web page?

Comment: can you post one  image.thb somewhere please, i want to make some test . thanks

Comment: you can see this link https://www.file-extension.org/extensions/thb

Comment: i want an real image, on your link Anshu, there is no sample.thb file

Comment: @Melvita  ok.... You can add the image with .thb extantion.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `.thb` file format is not supported by browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Firefox does not support such a format, but apparently Safai and Ebb should support such a format.. The question is -- can it do it in an <img> tag, or if some other way is needed to display such a file.

Comment: @YirmiyahuFischer There is not a lot information about that file format. I suggest you can try to repaint it using canvas or convert it for compatibility with `<img>`.